# Why can't jQuery methods be stored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

It seems that you cannot do this with jQuery:

```
f = $("#someElement").text
f("Bar!")
```

On chrome it gives me this error: "TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'empty'"

Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/bdN4z/

Comment: `this` depends on how you call a function. That's the bottom line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bdN4z/1/

Comment: because the execution context of the function will be different

Comment: To my mind this is ugly but you could wrap it in another function: `f= function(x){$("#second").text(x);};` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdN4z/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text` function makes use of the `this` value internally.

The value of `this` depends on how you call the function.

When you call `$("#someElement").text()`, you are calling it in the context of an instance of jQuery. jQuery instances have an `empty` method.

When you call `f()` you are calling it in the context of the default object (`window`). `window` doesn't have an `empty` method.

Comment: I see. That kind of sucks though, I encountered it when I tried to be clever by passing the text function as a result callback from an ajax call :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide a context for the method to work properly...

how about this?

```
someElement = $("#someElement");
f = someElement.text.bind(someElement);
f("Bar!")
```

Comment: or `f = $.fn.text.bind(someElement);` or in jQuery: `f = $.proxy($.fn.text, someElement);`

Comment: That kind of defeats the point, I was trying to be clever by passing the text function as a callback, the simple solution was to be a little less clever and passing it inside a closure :)

Comment: @monoceres but you can set context on callback method, what is your issue then?

Comment: @A.Wolff agreed. In any case, I think these kind of solutions are useful if one is creating a framework where every character and every millisecond saved is valuable, otherwise I go for readable solution, like `getChangeTextFn = function (el) {return function (newText) {el.text(newText);};};` so that if a junior looks at it in two months he doesn't go to stackoverflow *again*

Comment: I thought wrapping it was more readable and less "hacky". Compare the two different versions for my code: http://pastebin.com/B2Q7vBjm